# Custom InputFormat with Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

**Update**: Alright, it turns out the reason that the below isn't working is because I'm using a newer version of the `InputFormat` API (`import org.apache.hadoop.mapred` which is the old versus `import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce` which is the new).  The problem I have is porting the existing code to new code.  Has anyone had experience writing a multi-line `InputFormat` using the old API?

---

Trying to process Omniture's data log files with Hadoop/Hive.  The file format is tab delimited and while being pretty simple for the most part, they do allow you to have multiple new lines and tabs within a field that are escaped by a backslash (`\\n` and `\\t`).  As a result I've opted to create my own InputFormat to handle the multiple newlines and convert those tabs to spaces when Hive is going to try to do a split on the tabs.  I've just tried loading some sample data into the table in Hive and got the following error:

```
CREATE TABLE (...)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'OmnitureDataFileInputFormat' OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat';

FAILED: Error in semantic analysis: line 1:14 Input Format must implement InputFormat omniture_hit_data
```

The odd thing is that my input format does extend `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat` (https://gist.github.com/4a380409cd1497602906).

Does Hive require that you extend `org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat` instead? If so, do I have to rewrite any of my existing class code for the InputFormat and RecordReader or can I effectively just change the class it's extending?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured this out after looking at the code for LineReader and TextInputFormat.  Created a new InputFormat to deal with this as well as an EscapedLineReader.

https://github.com/msukmanowsky/OmnitureDataFileInputFormat