# How to store bank transaction data using Hive / Pig in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig

I have transaction data as shown below.

I need to store the data using Hive / Pig and should be able to query.

Can any one suggest me a way to store and retrieve the data shown below
( note: every new line starts with 0001)?

```
id  |cusid    |txndata

0001|000000001|01|0|AB...@GMAIL.COM|MR.XYZ|999 xxxx AVE|EDISON,               NJ|.|.|UNITED STATES - 08820|NRI|E|101601075073||
0001|000000001|02|2|101601075073|INR??21656|Savings|N|0|N| | | | | |
0001|000000001|04|0|N|??21656|000000000001|INR??43800|15-04-2011|43800|2.53|12|0|44919|15-04-2012|N
0001|000000001|04|0|N|??21656|000000000002|INR??43800|15-10-2011|44715|7|6|0|46292|15-04-2012|N
0001|000000001|04|0|N|??|000000000003|USD??1000|05-04-2011|1000|1.78|12|1|1018.23|06-04-2012|N
0001|000000001|15|0|000000000004??INR|000001|04-04-2011|B/F ||0|0|0|||AMEERPET|
0001|000000001|15|0|000000000001??INR|000002|26-04-2011|USD500@43.80LESSFCST25 ||0|21875.00|21875.00|||AMEERPET|15-04-2011
0001|000000001|15|0|000000000001??INR|000003|29-04-2011|DCARDFEE16004889APR11-MAR12+ST ||219.00|0|21656.00|||HYD SV ROAD|29-04-2011
0001|000000001|22|0|000000000001??INR|0||||||||||
0001|000000001|25|0|0.00|0.00||||||||||
0001|000000001|65||9401150684744302|625301222448|7|0|1664|2|01-07-2012| | | | |
```

Comment: Does this transaction contain sensitive information and is it here for our viewing pleasure?

Comment: Please remove or mask  any sensitive information before posting the data.

Comment: all the sensitive data has been masked already while posting.

Answer (score 0):

If the line terminator is '\n' it is pretty much straight forward. 
But If the line terminator is '0001' as of hive version 0.13 custom line terminators are not supported in hive. Default Line Terminator is '\n'.
 **LINES TERMINATED BY only supports newline '\n' right now**
This is resolved as per 
https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/DISTRO-498?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:changehistory-tabpanel.
we can implement Custom Input Format as a workaround.
[Custom InputFormat with Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692994/custom-inputformat-with-hive)
This will give more insight on how to implement